# Typescript Compiler of the App Deployed to Google App Engine does NOT resolve non-relative path

Tags: typescript, google-app-engine, nestjs

I'm trying to deploy my NestJS app to Google App Engine. At first, I added `"gcp-build"` and `"deploy"` to `package.json` scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "gcp-build": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "deploy": "gcloud app deploy",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "npm run start:prod",
    "start:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
}
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

At my local workspace, when I run `npm run start:dev`, the typescript compiler resolves every non-relative import path like `import {} from 'src/...'` to a relative path, so running the app is successful. However, every time I deploy the app to Google App Engine by runing `npm run deploy`, the console prints an error like `Error: Cannot find module 'src/auth/auth.service'`, implying that the compiler couldn't resolve non-relative paths. I also checked the compiled .js files in `dist` directory, and yes, the paths were not resolved:

```
const auth_service_1 = require("src/auth/auth.service");
```

I googled everywhere and the only solution I found was specifying `baseUrl` at `tsconfig.json`, which is what I already did. Is there any way I can try before changing every non-relative import path to the relative one? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't keep using `nest build` for your build command?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Since I installed nest-cli globally, so GAE cannot run nest cli scripts. May adding nest to package.json solve this issue?

Comment: Most nest projects have `@nestjs/cli` in the `devDependencies`, just like they have `typescript`

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Using `nest build` solved my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: To clarify, are you referring to build time or run time error when you say "the console prints an error like `Error: Cannot find module ...`"?

Comment: @g.delgado I think it was run time error since I uploaded the files without `dist` directory when deploying my project and GAE created `dist` directory in the cloud environment.

Comment: @RyanRo App Engine builds a docker container and runs `npm ci --quiet` on the project. If there's a `gcp-build` in your package json (which there is), it will subsequently run that as well. Since a `dist` folder was created, it does make sense that it would be a runtime issue for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest's `build` command from the `@nestjs/cli` will automatically try to resolve path aliases for you. If you aren't using the `@nestjs/cli` you'll need to use a third party package like `ts-config-paths`.